# Testing double axios request with jest in react app

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

My application had a problem with calling the API 2 times in componentDidMount. I fixed it and now I wanted to make a test with Jest for this scenario.

```js
class ResultsPage extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
       // It is possible, after parent component state change to be callet again
       this.props.getResults();
    }

    render() {
       return "Some JSX";
    }
}
```

How I can test this request. Do I need to test it in the component or to write some general test for Axios?

Comment: Do you want to test if this function has been called once? Or something else?

Comment: When the state of the parent Component is changed it re-render the ResultsPage component it is unmounted and mounted again. I am searching for a suggestion about how I can test is this componentDidMount is executed twice or if axios made 2 request for that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit test for `ResultsPage` is unable to test that. It's up to parent if some component is re-created or updated.

So if you really want to test that(I'm not sure if this provides any profit) you

1. Spy on `componentDidMount` for `ResultsPage`
2. `mount()` parent component
3. validate that spy for `componentDidMount` has been called only once.

```
const cDMspy = jest.spyOn(ResultsPage.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
mount(<SomeParent />);
expect(cDMspy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

In general case, things become harder if you expect few legal instances of `ResultsPage` in the same parent. Then validation for `.toHaveBeenCalledTimes` is not enough: it matters if we have 2 component instances with cDM called once per component or just single instance with cDM been called twice.

```
const cDMspy = jest.spyOn(ResultsPage.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
const wrapper = mount(<SomeParent />);
expect(wrapper.find(ResultsPage)).toHaveLength(2);
expect(cDMspy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
```

In case of cDM we may just check amount of component instances should be equal to calls count. But for other methods(that are not guaranteed to be called at least once per instance) we may end with creating our own tracking tool:

```
const callContext = [];
const original = ResultsPage.prototype.someMethod;
const spy = jest.spyOn(ResultsPage.prototype, someMethod);
spy.mockImplementation((...args) => {
  callContext.push(this.props.someMeaningfullPropToIdentityComponent);
  return original.call(this, ...args);
});

mount(<SomeParent />);
expect(callContext).toEqual(["id1", "id3", "id3"]);
```

See, it becomes much more complicated. Reasons becomes unclear, code becomes harder to maintain. Also any future refactoring like changing calls order, renaming methods supposed to be private etc breaks our test really bad.

What's alternative? You may mock things that should respond exactly N times(say `mockFn.mockReturnValueOnce` or any equivalent for axios mocks). Then just run your existing test cases and once something is requesting with unexpected frequency - you will know.

What's else? You may avoid focusing on that. In typical CRUD only creation should lead to dramatic results if called extra time. Everything else(deleting, updating, fetching) is more about performance then functionality. So it'd easier to test that alongside other performance-related things manually and on-demand(once there are issues with that).